# How do i get a button to clear the window in python tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a math's game which is a quiz. The math's quiz has a home page, then a page which contains the questions, then a page which tells you what you scored once finished. I have 3 different difficulties easy, medium and hard.

how do i clear what i have in my home page once i press the 'EASY' button to start the new quiz 'window' which will delete 2 label's and the three buttons. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You should share a short example of executable code that we can use to help you answer your question. The answer is likely to be to have a function that is called when the "EASY" button is pressed which then empties the contents of the page and resets any other variables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i clear a window after pressing a button in Python Tkinter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748378/how-do-i-clear-a-window-after-pressing-a-button-in-python-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

If you put all your widgets in one frame, inside the window, like this:

```
root=Tk()
main=Frame(root)
main.pack()
widget=Button(main, text='whatever', command=dosomething)
widget.pack()
etc.
```

Then you can clear the screen like this:

```
main.destroy()
main=Frame(root)
```

Or in a button:

```
def clear():
    global main, root
    main.destroy()
    main=Frame(root)
    main.pack()
clearbtn=Button(main, text='clear', command=clear)
clearbtn.pack()
```

To clear the screen.

Comment: Hi thanks for the anwser, this should help with my code!

Comment: @JohnKey If an answer solves your problem, you can press the green tick on it. It means that future people with your problem can see the answer more easily, as well as awarding you 2rep and the answerer 15rep.